# ¿Como podria autogenerar codigo de tipo cadena?

Tags: java, array, string, lista, contador

Tengo la duda en como poder autogenerar codigos de tipo cadena con un contador

es decir:

e001
e002
e003
e004
...

el siguiente codigo esta generando 
e000
e000
e000
e000

si alguien me pudiera ayudar seria genial, gracias

```js
public class alumnoMemory implements ICrudService<alumno>
{
    List<alumno> alumnos = new ArrayList<>();
    
    static int cont;
    static String conte;
    
    static
    {
        cont = 0;
        conte="e00" + cont;
        
    }
    @Override
    public void create(alumno obj) {
        cont++;
        obj.setId(conte);
        alumnos.add(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: conte="e00" + cont; eso ponlo en la función create luego de cont++;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo debes agregarlo luego de obtener el numero, es decir:

```
conte="e00" + cont;
```

eso ponlo en la función create luego de `cont++;`.

```
public class alumnoMemory implements ICrudService<alumno>
{
   List<alumno> alumnos = new ArrayList<>();
   static int cont;
   static String conte;
   static 
   { 
      cont = 0;
   }
   @Override
   public void create(alumno obj)
   {
      cont++;
      conte="e00" + cont;
      obj.setId(conte);
      alumnos.add(obj);
   }
}
```

Comment: Con este código, de "e009" pasarás a "e0010", cuando lo más normal es querer pasar a "e010".

Comment: Que agregue los ceros mediante una condicional que verifique la cantidad de numeros de cont++